# jQuery function it does not get called

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello everyone hope you are well.

I am trying to call a function in my jQuery file and for some reason it doesn't get called if I call it from an if statement. However the same function gets called for when I call it using .click().

The if statement works fine.

Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hello = 1;
    if (hello == 1) {
        console.log("True");
        helloWorld();
    } else {
        console.log("False");
    }
    $('#en').click(helloWorld(pathname));

    function helloWorld() {
        return function () {
            console.log("function called");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: var hello==1 ? this is a condition should not be var hello = 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function return another function, if you want to call it, this is the correct way:

```
helloWorld()();
```

Or

```
var myFunc = helloWorld();
myFunc();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using

```
var hello==1;
```

instead of

```
var hello=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

When assigning `hello` variable, you test it if it is equal to `1`, not assigning `1` to variable. Just try with:

```
var hello = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration in variable is wrong.

var hello=1;